# socket.io and multiple rooms

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

From node.js I can send messages to all clients in room. But, on client side, in browser, can I connect client socket to different rooms (3-5 rooms), and receiving separate messages from all rooms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just have the client socket subscribe to each room.  When a message is sent to rooms the client is subscribed to, he will be able to receive those messages.

To differentiate between rooms the room name could be sent back to the client socket with any data the client needs.

Comment: I understand it, but no native support for room on client side?

Comment: I don't believe there is native support.  You would need to take care of it yourself.